# Ubuntu Hangs on Shutdown - End Trace Error

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown

When I try to shutdown ubuntu, with increasing frequency it gets stuck on a screen filled with text ending in [endtrace0xHEXCODE].

This happens when I use commands to turn off the computer as well. I looked it up and it seems like the problem could either be an ongoing kernel bug or a video driver issue.

What gives? How do I get my computer to shut all the way down every single time?

I use Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Are you using restricted drivers?

Comment: I use Broadcom wireless and ATI Radean graphics.